# How to update the values of nested dict in python?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am new to programming and currently learning python. I am stuck when trying out dictionaries in python. 
I have a normal dict with a key and the value as an empty string:

```
dict = {'Project_path':''},
        'Target_files':'',
        'default_ws':''}
```

I am updating the value of keys like this:

```
dict['project_path'] = 'Pass'
```

But I want to create a dict where I don't have to use long keys; instead I can map these keys to numbers so that if i want to update a dict i can do it  like this:

```
dict = {1:{'Project_path':''},
        2:{'Target_files':''},
        3:{'default_ws':''}} 
dict['1'] = 'pass'
```

It should update the value for `'project_path'` as `'pass'`

And after updating the values, I have to write this in a file

Is there way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Programming in Python! Few things here: First, using `dict` as a variable name is not a good idea, as this is a keyword for the whole class of dictionary objects. You can use something like, `my_dict`, or something like that.

Second, when you make the keys numbers and then call `dict['1'] = 'pass'` this looks for the string '1' in the keys, when you have declared the integer 1 as the key. Let me explain:

'1' is a string

1 is an integer.

In python these are two very different things and cannot be mixed around . That's why the value doesn't update. If you were to say `dict[1] = 'pass'`, that should work for you and it should update the values. Note, though that this will overwrite the whole dictionary that is the current value and replace it with 'pass', if instead you just want to change the dictionary key, use

`dict[1]['Project_path'] = 'pass'`.

This, however seems redundant to  me. It's kind of unclear exactly why you want to map integers in there (perhaps to loop through it and change values), but if you just want integers associated with it, you could just create and array of dictionaries like this:

```
my_array = [{"Project_path": ''}, {"Target_files":''}, {default_ws":''}]
```

Then, you could access them by their index starting at 0. `my_array[0]` is `{"Project_path":''}`. Again, it's kind of unclear why you want to map integers to these dicts, so it doesn't really make sense to me because this is a little redundant.

Finally, writing to a file. There's a lot of webpages out there, because there are many options when it comes to reading and writing files (like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)), but here's the short version.

```
with open('your_filepath.txt', 'w') as file: #note this will overwrite the current file, see the page I linked.
    file.write(my_array[0]) #or whatever you want to write to it.
```

It's that simple, but like I said, take a look at that page to see what all your options are and choose the best one for you. Hopefully that is helpful and can get you started.

Comment: Thanks SH7890 this helps a lot and regarding that mapping integers is just that i want to reuse the dict in other classes and update the values of the keys using loop........so just to avoid typos and writing long keys its better to have numbers so that i can update the values easily and just one more ques so after your array of dict now if i want to update the value for project_path = 'Pass' i can do that by indexing am i right?

Comment: `my_array[0]["Project_path"] = "Pass"` will change the value.

Comment: I know that you're a beginner, and you're heading in the right direction, but Python has some advanced features that you can use to loop through dictionaries and you should check them out once you get used to loops and data structures. Good luck in you endeavors!

Comment: Thanks i cannot use like my_array[0] = 'Pass' actually i want something like this, is it possible?

Comment: If you want to do that, then it would just be an array. `my_array = ["Number 0", "Index 1 value", "Another value"]` Then, `my_array[0] = "Pass"` would change the 0th value to "Pass"

Comment: Thanks a lot...got it

Comment: Great. If you want to learn more about python data structures (and don't mind reading documentation), [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html) is some of what there is to offer. It's kind of technical sometimes, but it's a good reference.